# How can I extract text and lists with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

### Start with BeautifulSoup I was using using SCRAPY to extract the [OER](https://www.oercommons.org/courses/randomized-synthesis-project) data but I have 3 problems with:

1. The **amount** of: visits, times saved .. because xpath used something like "/dl[2]/dd[2]/"

- with scrapy

  `cant_visitas = response.xpath ("//// i [@ class = 'fa fa-eye'] / following-sibling :: span [1] / text ()"). extract_first ()`
- with **BeautifulSoup** I can't extract the value (someone knows if it **is possible** to use a **tag with spaces**)

  `cant_guardados = soup.find ('li', {'id': 'Number of saves'}) #. find ('span'). get_text ()`

2. And the **lists** as is the case of the degrees **.getall()** (with JSON TYPE return) in BeautifulSoup it seems that it is **find_all** only that I don't know how to do it because using xpath "everything is nested dl [2] / dd [3 ] "

- with scrapy

  `degrees = response.xpath ('normalize-space (// div [@ class = "material-details"] / dl [2] / dd [3] / text ())'). getall ()`
- with **BeautifulSoup**

  `degrees = soup.find ('div', 'material-details'). select ('dl: nth-of-type (2)> dd: nth-of-type (3)')`

3. How could I extract the average value of the valuation, since it is found as an attribute of the div

```py
amount_stars = soup.find('div', 'item-rating').find('div', 'stars').find_all('i', 'active-star') #div data-rating-value
amount_stars = len(amount_stars)
```

This brings the number of active stars not their actual rating

PS: I think the closest thing to xpath in **BeautifulSoup** is the select but the safest thing is that I'm wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script will get all information from the webpage using CSS selectors:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.oercommons.org/courses/randomized-synthesis-project'

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

number_of_visits = soup.select_one('[title="Number of visits"]').get_text(strip=True)
number_of_saves  = soup.select_one('[title="Number of saves"]').get_text(strip=True)
material_type = soup.select_one('dt:contains("Material Type:") + dd').get_text(strip=True)
data_rating = soup.select_one('[data-rating-value]')['data-rating-value']

print('Number of visits: {}'.format(number_of_visits))
print('Number of saves : {}'.format(number_of_saves))
print('Material type   : {}'.format(material_type))
print('Data rating     : {}'.format(data_rating))
```

Prints:

```
Number of visits: 62
Number of saves : 3
Material type   : Activity/Lab,Lesson
Data rating     : 0.0
```

---

More about CSS selectors [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).

---

EDIT: This should be compatible with `BeautifulSoup 4.6.0`:

```
number_of_visits = soup.select_one('[title="Number of visits"]').get_text(strip=True)
number_of_saves  = soup.select_one('[title="Number of saves"]').get_text(strip=True)
material_type = soup.find(lambda tag: tag.name=='dt' and 'Material Type:' in tag.text).find_next('dd').get_text(strip=True)
data_rating = soup.select_one('[data-rating-value]')['data-rating-value']
```

Comment: thanks for the help almost everything works for the material it throws me `'Only the following pseudo-classes are implemented: nth-of-type.')
NotImplementedError: Only the following pseudo-classes are implemented: nth-of-type.` I suppose it may be because some OER do not have material or have more than one ** but it works for you ** maybe another way

Comment: @Cristian That means you're using old version of BeautifulSoup, I use `beautifulsoup4==4.9.1`

Comment: is version 4.6.0

Comment: @Cristian Upgrade it to latest, to be able to use CSS selectors.

Comment: it's a collaborative project if I do they send me to the devil hehehe in addition to that we have already advanced something even so that was the one that was installed by default... this version has come out these days that explains it

Comment: @Cristian OK, I understand... I updated my question and added new version that should be compatible with old version of BeautifulSoup